# How to unit test if consumer ran successfully in MassTransit when no response

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-webapi, masstransit

Im  writing unit test that should validate if a consumer ran successfully. But for some reason the consumer executes and gives result false always. I am missing the act to mock the consumer i think.?

Here is my code which is causing the problem while writing unit test case in MassTransit.

```
 [SetUp]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    
        serviceCollection.AddMassTransitTestHarness(busRegistrationConfigurator =>
        {
            busRegistrationConfigurator.AddConsumer<MyConsumer>();
        });
    
        var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    
        _testHarness = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITestHarness>();
    }
    
    
    [Test]
   
    public async Task TestMethod1()
    {
        await _testHarness.Start();
        await _testHarness.Bus.Publish(new MyEvent { Code = "H"});
    
        Assert.That(await _testHarness.Published.Any<MyEvent>(), Is.True);//This is true
        Assert.That(await _testHarness.Consumed.Any<MyEvent>(), Is.True);  //This is false always
    }
```

The second assertion gives me false always:

I was going through the documentations of MassTransit regarding testing. But didnt make it work .The consumer just insert data to database. The sample code provided in my example does not involves a request and response.

Would very much appreciate any help!

Comment: You can use the TestHarness class in MassTransit to test the consumer. The TestHarness class provides a simple way to test consumers in isolation, without the need for a bus instance or a message broker. You can use the TestHarness class to send messages
 to a consumer and verify that the consumer handles the messages correctly.

Comment: In your code, you are using the TestHarness class to start the bus and publish an event. However, you are not waiting for the consumer to handle the event before checking if it was consumed. To fix this, you can use the Consumed property of the TestHarness
 class to wait for the consumer to handle the event.